# Unable to save picture from url to my server

Tags: php, image, curl, download

I'm try to save some pictures from url to my server, but i'm not able to do it.

this is my code (it's standard, i've found on internet):

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
 $fp = fopen($img, 'wb');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 fclose($fp);
```

but for each link i put inside $url variable, on my server is always saved a 26 byte image (that's not the original image).
What's wrong?

Comment: The file i would download is a picture, and $img is a string like "myFolder/temp.jpg

Comment: what is that 26 byte image? also you can always use `file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));`

Comment: it's a broken image, i couldn't see correctly. If i use file_put_contents i obtain a 0 byte image. As i could read, not all server admit to use that function to get files

Comment: so it's looks like server problem? ask your admin about it

Comment: What is the URI you are trying to request?

Comment: i'm try with different image found randomly on google image

Comment: could you post one example?

Comment: i've try with this variables:

$url = "http://www.letteratu.it/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/cielo.jpg";

$img = "/img/img.jpg";

Comment: Have you tried outputting `curl_error($ch)` somewhere to see if it is telling you an error?

Comment: i obtain "destination host forbidden"

Comment: That looks like a cross-origin issue. Someone mentioned that adding this made it work for them: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');`

Answer (score 1):

I can successfully download image using your curl code. It can happen that your server is not allowed to connect the outside web links.

This is a curl equivalent code that download images as well. I believe from your server, you can not download image using this code.

```
file_put_contents("img.jpg", file_get_contents("http://www.letteratu.it/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/cielo.jpg"));
```

Run your curl with verbose mode to see the curl's debug messages, and show that us.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
```

Comment: Amazing answer! file_get_contents in the second parameter solved my problem also! Didn't know about it!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you need to include the `http://` in the URL. I'm fairly certain it thinks that it is a local file without it (i.e., an implicit `file://`).